# Character group of torus over the real numbers (Theorie de Hodge II)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, hodge-theory

I am trying to read the article *Théorie de Hodge II* (which can be found in French [here](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number15.pdf)) and in page 24, when Deligne starts discussing Hodge structures, he makes the following claim about the character group of the torus $S=\mathrm{Res}_{\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{G}_m)$ (the multiplicative group 
 on $\mathbb{C}$):
$$
\mathrm{X}(S)=\mathrm{Hom}(S_\mathbb{C},\mathbb{G}_{m})=Hom(S,\mathbb{G}_m)(\mathbb{C})
$$
I understand that the first equality is just the definition and that multiplicative group on the middle is the multiplicative group over $\mathbb{C}$, whereas the one on the right is over $\mathbb{R}$. However, I don't get the notation $Hom(S,\mathbb{G}_m)(\mathbb{C})$, since $Hom(S,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is an abelian group. I have seen somewhere that this could mean tensor product with $\mathbb{C}$, but that doesn't fit with my intuition that the group $\mathrm{Hom}(S_\mathbb{C},\mathbb{G}_{m})$ should be free abelian of rank 2. Also, I don't get at all the sudden change to italic letters for the $\mathrm{Hom}$ (in case it is not a typo).

Thanks for any kind of help you may provide.